# Programmatically setting checkbox checked attribute in IE 10

Tags: javascript, checkbox, internet-explorer-10, checked

I have a legacy page which uses a ton of raw javascript (no JS library hiding browser differences).  It dynamically creates a checkbox like this:

```
function createCheckbox(checkboxName, isChecked, onClickHandler)
{
    var checkboxId = checkboxName + 'ChkBx';
    var chkbx;

    if(Ext.isIE)
    {
        // Following code does not work in IE10 when NOT using compatibility view
        // Throws JS error.  Worked in IE9.
        //if (isChecked)
        //{
        //    chkbx = document.createElement('<input id="' + checkboxId + '" type="checkbox" name="' + checkboxName + '" value="true" checked="checked" className="checkbox" />');
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    chkbx = document.createElement('<input id="' + checkboxId + '" type="checkbox" name="' + checkboxName + '" value="true" className="checkbox" />');
        //}

        // Following code does not work in IE10 when using compatibility view
        // isChecked == true does not product checked checkbox
        chkbx = document.createElement('input');
        chkbx.id = checkboxId;
        chkbx.name = checkboxName;
        chkbx.value = 'true';
        chkbx.type = 'checkbox';
        chkbx.checked = isChecked;
        chkbx.className = 'checkbox';
    }
    else 
    { ... }

    return chkbx;    
}
```

I understand that in IE10, createElement() no longer accepts elaborate string parameters.  That is why I changed the code above. What I don't understand is why, it does not respect my setting the checked attribute to true?  How else is one supposed to indicate that the checkbox should be checked?

Comment: That should work fine; what exactly is the value of "isChecked"?

Answer (score 2):

add

`chkbx.defaultChecked = isChecked;`

Problem solved.

When using compatibility view, IE10 could falls back to IE7 way of doing things. (depends on your settings)

Source: [Checkboxes will not check in IE7 using Javascript, and yet no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049396/checkboxes-will-not-check-in-ie7-using-javascript-and-yet-no-errors)

Tested with IE 10.0.9200.16519